# JQuery Mobile How to send the audio file to server

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have implemented a app for android using phone Gap.

In the app I have two button one is Voice Enroll and another one is Voice Verification.

For Voice Enroll I implemented Record Function Using CaptureAudio in Phone Gap. It works Great.

Now I need to upload the Record file to server. I have Used Below Code.

```
function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
 var i, len;
 for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
alert(mediaFiles[i]);
      uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
 }       
}


 function captureError(error) {
 var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
 navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');
 }


 function captureAudio() {
 navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 3);
 }

 // Upload files to server
 function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
 var ft = new FileTransfer(),
 recordingPath = mediaFile.fullPath,
 name = mediaFile.name;

 console.log('Path is: ' + recordingPath);

 ft.upload(recordingPath,
           "Webservice URL",
           function(result) {
alert("Hi");
           console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
           console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
           },
           function(error) {
alert("welcome");
           console.log('Error uploading file ' + recordingPath + ': ' + error.code);
           },
           { fileName: name });   

   alert(recordingPath);
}
```

When I alert that mediaFiles[i] is received "Object Object". I can't receive any response after uploading.

Once Success we receive some messages from server about the audio file.

I am also send the audio file name as 'utterence'. How can i done this using phonegap and jquery mobile?

Comment: wats der in recordingPath ?

Comment: @DiveshSalian ~ Recorded audio file path

Comment: Try uploading 1 File. I mean record only 1 audio and check

Comment: I already checked no response

Comment: Try debugging on server.... Check if ur request is received or not and using HTTPS ?

Comment: Uplad it with AJAX

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a similar problem and in my case the problem was capture returned full path and upload required the file path in different format so I had to modify the full path in a format accepted by upload.

Also make sure you set mimeType in the upload function. It defaults to image/jpeg. I am not sure how your server behaves but if it has self signed certificates then you will have to set trustAllHosts to true.

Hope this helps